# Passing document YAML options to rmarkdown::render function to adjust page margins and font

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdf-generation

I'd like to render a simple markdown file, that has been created by another process before, into a pdf file.

The command:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "my_report.md", 
                  output_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document(latex_engine = "xelatex"))
```

just does this job.

However I would like to change the margins and the main font.
With an `.Rmd` file one would define these settings in the Yaml header like this:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: LiberationSans
geometry: "left=5cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
---
```

But the markdown files I'd like to convert don't have a Yaml header. Is there a way to pass these Yaml options to the `render` function as function parameters or in an indirect way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 01

`geometry`, `mainfont` are [`Pandoc variables`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) and you can pass them to `rmarkdown::pdf_document` via [`pandoc_args`](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/rmarkdown/reference/pdf_document.html) argument.

And for convenience, you can use [`rmarkdown::pandoc_variable_arg`](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/rmarkdown//reference/pandoc_args.html) to specify name-value pair of pandoc arguments. And you need to use `template=NULL` so that rmarkdown default template is not used (otherwise whatever variable value passed to `pandoc_arg` get appended by `geometry:margin=1in`, so yours specified geometry value wiil be overwritten by rmarkdown defaults).

```
library(rmarkdown)

render(
  input = "input.md",
  output_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document(
    latex_engine = "xelatex",
    template = NULL,
    pandoc_args = c(
      pandoc_variable_arg("geometry", "left=5cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"),
      pandoc_variable_arg("mainfont", "LiberationSans")
    )
  )
)
```

And we can see that the variables are passed to pandoc correctly,

> ```
> /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS 
> input.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash 
> --output input.tex --lua-filter /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua 
> --lua-filter /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua 
> --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango 
> --pdf-engine xelatex 
> --variable geometry=left=5cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm 
> --variable mainfont=LiberationSans
> ```

### Option 02

Alternatively, you can pass those YAML options from a yaml file (located in the same directory as the input markdown file) via [`--metadata-file`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) pandoc args.

So specify the [pandoc variables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables) name and value in a yaml file like as following,

**main.yml**

```
author: Jphn Doe
mainfont: LiberationSans
geometry:
  - left=5cm
  - top=2cm
  - right=3cm
  - bottom=2cm
linestretch: 1.5
pagestyle: headings
```

and then run the `rmarkdown::render`, (here you still need to use `template=NULL`, other wise the geometry you have specified in `main.yml` will be overwritten by rmardown default `geometry:margin=1in`)

```
library(rmarkdown)

render(
  input = "test_yaml.md",
  output_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document(
    latex_engine = "xelatex",
    template = NULL,
    pandoc_args = c("--metadata-file", "main.yml")
  )
)
```

---

**input.md** (markdown file used to test the code)

```
# Rmarkdown

Hello from rmarkdown.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio nec ornare tempor semper eget. Ligula lorem,
torquent ante mauris torquent feugiat dis finibus vitae.
```

**Output for 1st option**

[image: pdf output]

**Output from 2nd option**

[image: pdf output]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but only using some trickery, and it might not work for all possible arguments.  It does seem to work for `mainfont` and `geometry`.

The way those settings are passed to LaTeX is as Pandoc variables which are inserted into the template.  The trouble is, the `pdf_document` driver hardcodes margins of 1in if you don't have them in your YAML, and those are added to the Pandoc command line right near the end.  You need to override that setting even later.

Here's one way to do it.  Create your own output format that is based on `pdf_document`, but which adds its own variable settings right at the end.
For example,

```
my_pdf_document <- function(geometry, mainfont, ...) {
  force(geometry)
  force(mainfont)
  result <- rmarkdown::pdf_document(...)
  oldpreproc <- result$pre_processor
  result$pre_processor <- function(...) {
    c(oldpreproc(...),
      "--variable",
      paste0("geometry:", geometry),
      "--variable",
      paste0("mainfont:", mainfont))
  }
  result
}
```

When you want to render using this preprocessor, give the arguments you would have given to `pdf_document` as well as the ones being set using Pandoc variables, e.g.

```
rmarkdown::render("test.md",
              output_format = my_pdf_document(
                geometry = "left=5cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm", 
                mainfont = "Helvetica", 
                latex_engine="xelatex")
             )
```

When I make the call above, I see a Pandoc command that looks like this:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc
  +RTS -K512m -RTS test.md --to latex --from
  markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash 
  --output test.tex 
  --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua 
  --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua 
  --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango 
  --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics 
  --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
  --variable 'geometry:left=5cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm' 
  --variable 'mainfont:Helvetica'
```

(though it's all on one long line, not wrapped so neatly).  The 3rd last line is the problematic margin setting, and the last two lines are the result of our special output format.

EDITED to add:

An easier, less hacky approach to this would be to read the entire Markdown file and write it out again with a YAML header.  Then you can put whatever you like in the header, and it'll work if a hard coded version would work.

Comment: Nice solution! I was trying with `pandoc_args` option and passing variable-name with `pandoc_variable_arg`. Everything works fine except that `geometry:margin=1in`, because doing a quick go through over source code of `pdf_document`, it seems whatever passed to `pandoc_args` get appended before `--variable geometry:margin=1in`.